# Scatter chart - Convertible filling between with and without

Tags: excel, vba, scatter, excel-charts

With these codes I want to make convertable XY scattered chart with filling and without filling marker.
But once marker is converted to without filling and return to with filling, the marker is not converted to without filling anymore.
If I save and close, then it works again.
Would you please recommend which point I need to update?

Convert to without filling

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
Selection.MarkerSize = 10
With Selection
    .Format.Fill.Visible = False
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    .Format.Line.Weight = 1
    .Border.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone 'Remove lines between points
End With
```

Convert to with filling

```
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
Selection.MarkerSize = 10
With Selection
    .Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Format.Fill.Solid
    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 100, 0)
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    .Format.Line.Weight = 5
    .Border.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone 'Remove lines between points
End With
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
Sub test1()
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim Srs As Series
    
    Set Cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    Set Srs = Cht.SeriesCollection(1)
    
    With Srs
        .MarkerSize = 10
        .Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Format.Line.Weight = 1
        .Border.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone 'Remove lines between points
    End With
End Sub
Sub test2()
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim Srs As Series
    
    Set Cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    Set Srs = Cht.SeriesCollection(1)
    
    With Srs
        .MarkerSize = 10
        .Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
        .Format.Line.Weight = 5
        .Border.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone 'Remove lines between points
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for checking. Test 1 works for removing filling. but test 2 does not recover filling.